# how to push returned data to array after subscribe in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a tree structure like this:

```
[{
 number: 3,
 children: [{
number: 6,
children: [{
  number: 8,
  children: []
}]
}, {
number: 7,
children: [{
  number: 9,
  children: [{
    number: 8,
    children: []
  }]
}]
}, {
number: 8,
children: []
}, {
number: 9,
children: [{
  number: 8,
  children: []
}]
}]
}];
```

This is my method:

```
  result.subscribe((x) => {
  this.phonebookTreeModel.items = {};
  this.phonebookTreeModel.items.children = [];
  let array: any[] = [];
  x.items.forEach((item) => {
    console.log('items', item);
    if (item.parentId == 0 || item.parentId == null) {
      this.childrenArray = x.items.filter((i) => i.parentId == item.id);
      this.phonebookTreeModel.items.created = item.created;
      this.phonebookTreeModel.items.id = item.id;
      this.phonebookTreeModel.items.name = item.name;
      this.phonebookTreeModel.items.parentId = item.parentId;
      if (this.childrenArray.length > 0) {
        this.childrenArray.forEach((child) => {
          this.phonebookTreeModel.items.children.push(child);
        });
      }
      array.push(this.phonebookTreeModel);
    }
  });
  console.log('array is', array);
});
```

the returned data is an array that each item has a parentId.
I'm trying to create it with another model that I created with foreach loop but it only returns the last item several times like this:
[image]

my items are like this:
[image]
I think it's because of the 'subscribe' that make this process asynchronous but I don't want it to be asynchronous. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. use `variable$ = new BehaviorSubject<DATA_TYPE>();`
2. at the end of logic: `this.variable$.next(NEW_VALUE_HERE);`
3. html: `variable$ | async`

P.S. don't forget next:
`.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))` before call `.subscribe(/**/)`

```
private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>(false);
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

**code will looks like below**:

```
@Components({
    template: `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn">{{item?.id}}</ng-container>`
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public array$ = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);
    private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>(false);
    constructor(/**/) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        /* somewhere in code */
        this.SOME_SERVICE.SOME_METHOD()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe(x => {
            this.phonebookTreeModel.items = {};
            this.phonebookTreeModel.items.children = [];
            const array: Array<any> = [];
            x.items.forEach((item) => {
                if (item.parentId == 0 || item.parentId == null) {
                    this.childrenArray = x.items.filter((i) => i.parentId == item.id);
                    this.phonebookTreeModel.items.created = item.created;
                    this.phonebookTreeModel.items.id = item.id;
                    this.phonebookTreeModel.items.name = item.name;
                    this.phonebookTreeModel.items.parentId = item.parentId;
                    if (this.childrenArray.length > 0) {
                        this.childrenArray.forEach((child) => {
                            this.phonebookTreeModel.items.children.push(child);
                        });
                    }
                    array.push(this.phonebookTreeModel);
                }
            });
            this.array$.next(array);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next(true);
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }

    trackByFn(index, item) {
        return item.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but I really don't understand how should I write it

Comment: sorry but it's not working. It returns array like in the question.

Comment: when problem in logic